# How to turn trackball LED on in Android from code?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, led, trackball

Is there any way to do this? I've found something [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-hardware-indicators-with-the-android-sdk--mobile-2274), but it does not work for me:/

This is the code I,ve tried:

```
NotificationManager notifMgr = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
Notification notif = new Notification();
notif.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notif.ledOnMS = 1;
notif.ledOffMS = 0;

notifMgr.notify( 1234, notif );
```

Comment: What happens if you set ledOnMS = 2000; and ledOffMS = 500; ? Also, try Color.RED, green or white, maybe your hardware can't display blue.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that LEDs are under the control of the device manufacturer, and they do not need to use them for notifications.